# How to make browser recognize user's resolution?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to make the browser recognize the user's resolution and redirect him to my specific page? something like that:

```
var wid=screen.width;
var hei=screen.height;

if ((wid = 1024) && (hei = 768)) {
window.redirect('page1024x768.html',"blank")
}

else {


((wid = 800) && (hei == 600)) {
window.open(page800x600.html',"_blank")
}

else {

window.open('page1366x768',"_blank")
```

I tried but it's not working, is the code wrong?

Comment: If this is a direct copy/paste, your syntax and quotes are messed up.

Comment: _“is the code wrong?”_ – the whole approach is wrong already. Go read up on _media queries_.

Comment: 800×600?  whoa it's like 1998.  why do you have separate pages for a handful of resolutions?  just design a page that adapts to resolution, and use `@media` queries if absolutely necessary.  note that the screen resolution doesn't tell you the size of the browser window, either; not everyone runs their browser maximized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most immediately, your problems are that

1. you're using `=` (assignment) rather than `==` (equality testing);
2. you probably want to use `location.replace` rather than `window.open`;
3. you're missing an opening quote; and
4. you're missing a closing brace.

However, keep in mind that if this only runs on page load, then if someone changes their screen resolution, it won't adjust; search engines like Google might not like duplication of content; and what if someone has some other, more obscure resolution (like me, in fact)? A much better solution would be to use, say, CSS media queries [as pointed out by Dhaivat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19484367).

Comment: It won't matter if the user resizes the browser, as this code checks the screen's size, and not the size of the browser.

Comment: @skimberk1: Good catch. I guess I really meant to say if they change their screen resolution, which would be a rarer occurrence.

Comment: Yeah, media queries should definitely be a better solution.

Comment: After viewing the website i realized that indeed media queries is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript for this, but it will probably be much easier/better to style your pages using CSS's [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Theoritically that code should work, but it's got quite a few syntax errors.

Fixed code:

```
var wid = screen.width;
var hei = screen.height;

if (wid == 1024 && hei == 768) {
    window.redirect('page1024x768.html',"blank");
}

else if (wid == 800 && hei == 600) {
    window.open('page800x600.html',"_blank")
}

else {
    window.open('page1366x768',"_blank")
}
```